# mongoose find query : find match by referring to a specific property of an object in an array of objects

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I would like to create a query doing something like this :

```
model.find({'UDID': { listOfobjects[i].UDID }})
```

i understand this is not a legal way to write it but i is for going through all the objects in the array 
i would like to go through all the objects in the array referring to the property UDID of each object

the `$in` operator is good for array containing simple objects, i need to do the same with array of objects and refer to a specific property for each object. something like :

```
model.find({'UDID': {$in : listOfobjects.UDID }})
```

I think it suppose to be a mix of `$in` and `findById` but i really have no clue how to do that.

I would really appreciate you help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is currentply possible in mongodb. But you could do something like the following which would really be the shortcut mongodb would be doing if it did have this feature.

```
model.find({'UDID': {$in: listOfObjects.map(function(o) { return o.UDID; }) }});
```